# How can I make a field required from a drop down list using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a class fields with an ID of "sales-representative" require when a drop down list value is "Yes". Right now I have this and it's not working. I'm new in Java Script. If someone can help me I'll appreciate it.

```
`<script>
    var makeSRFieldsRequired = function(){
if (document.getElementById("soa-coordinated-drp").value = "YES"){
document.getElementById("sales-representative").prop('required', required);}
    };
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question all that well, but from what I gathered you were after a solution to toggle a dropdown dependant upon the action of another dropdown.

Below is the code I wrote in order to do this, we are listening everytime a change is made to the dropdown which in this case has an id of `value-to-yes` when the change is made we're seeing what the selected index so in this case, 1 is equal to yes.

If it is equal to yes, we show the other dropdown.

If not, then we hide it.

```js
var selectYes = document.querySelector('#value-to-yes');
var sales = document.querySelector('#sales-representative');

selectYes.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (selectYes.selectedIndex === 1) {
      sales.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      sales.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="value-to-yes">
  <option selected hidden>Please select an option</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<form id="sales-representative" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID" required>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that's perfect but I need to make a input field required if the value of the dropdown is "YES".

Comment: What do you mean? Which input field needs to be required?

Comment: I have a dropdown in a form that ask if a Sales Representative is needed. If the value of the dropdown is "YES", I want  to make a script for the input field "Name", "ID" and "Phone Number" required to prevent that the form is send without that information.

Comment: I have updated my answer you can just add `required` onto a input field and it will make it so the form doesn't submit without the data in those input fields.